# Замена (а не добавление) измененных значений mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Считываю ключи/значения (их несколько) из Local Storage и отправляю на сервер:

```
 var ret = [];
 for (var i = localStorage.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

 k_ls = localStorage.key(i)
 v_ls = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))

 ret.push('(' +  "'" + k_ls + "'" + ',' + "'" + v_ls + "'" + ')');
 }

 var text = ret.join(',');

 $.get( "http://blabla.com/update.php", {x:text})
 .done(function( data ) {......
 });
```

На сервере вставляю в таблицу:

```
 $text = $_GET['x'];
 mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO `1221` (k_ls, v_ls) VALUES $text");
```

Можно ли "обновлять" значения в Mysql? Например я поменял старый ключ в Local Storage, отправил, и значение ключа обновилось, а не появилась новая строка. Или я просто повторно запустил скрипт и значения в Mysql остались прежними, не продублировались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужен запрос вида **[INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**.
При этом надо, чтобы те колонки, по которым будет происходить insert/update были уникальными (например связка `k_ls, v_ls` - уникальна)

Пример запроса:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `text`) 
VALUES (3, 'tra-ta-ta')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
```

где вместо `id` и `text` - ваши поля

---

Также можно попробовать использовать `REPLACE TO` вместо `INSERT TO` , в этом случае запись перезапишется в случае существования или создастся новая, если таких ключей раньше не было. Только в случае `REPLACE`, старая запись удалится, а потом вставится новая с теми же ключами. А также если существуют constraints с действиями `ON DELETE CASCADE`, то данные могут погибнуть.

Пример:

```
REPLACE INTO `table` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (3, 'tra-ta-ta')
```

Comment: Вы хотели сказать `ON DUPLICATE KEY` срабатывает на попытке вставки дублирующихся значений в первичный ключ или в поле с уникальным индексом.

Comment: @vikolyada угу.

Comment: Спасибо, но сделал все по первому варианту - записи вообще перестали вставляться. Со вторым  - не смог найти команду REPLACE TO в интернете. Приведите пожалуйста пример для моего случая

Comment: @Nik `но сделал все по первому варианту - записи вообще перестали вставляться` -  надеюсь вы не в точности скопипастили с ответа. ведь это лишь пример был. у вас будет что-то типа `"INSERT INTO \`1221\` (\`k_ls\`, \`v_ls\`) 
VALUES ({$val1}, '{$val2}')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \`k_ls\` = {$val1}, \`v_ls\`= '{$val2}';` ......А не получается у вас скорее всего потому, что вы в JS формируете динамически VALUES.... что неправильно... нужно это делать в PHP. именно из-за `DUPLICATE KEY`....

Comment: @Nik так как при его использовании надо указывать по одной колонке что вы хотите обновить (см. комментарий выше), а у вас переменная содержит уже целую строку `(1231, "sdfsdfds")`, вот и происходит ошибка ................ пример `REPLACE` добавил....... по сути вы просто меняете слово `INSERT` на  `REPLACE` не более

Comment: Нет конечно, я не просто скопипастил) у меня на выходе примерно так: INSERT INTO `1221` (`k_ls`, `v_ls`) VALUES (('blabla','12'),('blabla','1221'),('bla1','1')) т.е. значений - ключей несколько и всегда разное количество)

Comment: @Nik ааа. там даже несколько... тогда надо будет писать через `VALUES` ... так  `"INSERT INTO \`1221\` (k_ls, v_ls) VALUES $text ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
k_ls = VALUES(k_ls),
v_ls = VALUES(v_ls)";` ......такой запрос должен обновить именно мультизначения...... то есть в строках `k_ls = VALUES(k_ls)` и `v_ls = VALUES(v_ls)` именно так надо будет писать уже без подстановки переменных